# Why is my Rsquare inconsistent with the Pearson correlation coefficient?

Tags: statistics

I have a correlation matrix which shows a 0.93 correlation between two parameters.
When I create a linear model between the two parameters I get a 0.53 R-square. How is this possible?

Comment: Hi Janet, This is more a Cross-Validated question than a StackOverflow question. We wouldn't be able to help you otherwise without a reproducible answer. Also, please do not use the Rstudio tag if your question is not related to the IDE.

Comment: Thank you, actually my Pearson coefficient comes from a correlation matrix between multiple variables. When I run a Pearson test between the two variables I want to evaluate with the following code "data:  data$Var1 and dataVar2" I get still another result that looks like the mean of my R-square and the coeff of Pearson from the matrix: 
t = 4.2778, df = 16, p-value = 0.0005767
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3999465 0.8928301
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.7304287...